# not getting Email id from fbsdk in react native

Tags: android, ios, facebook, email, react-native

I am getting login success and accessToken  .  I made

I tried

```
LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions([
      'email',
      'public_profile',
      'user_likes',
    ])
```

then this

```
LoginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions([
  'publish_actions',
]).then((result) => {
  if (result.isCancelled) {
    console.log('Login cancelled');
  } else {
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then((data) => {
      const accessToken = data.accessToken;
      const responseInfoCallback = (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          console.log('Error fetching data=', error.toString());
        } else {
          console.log('Success fetching data=', result.toString());
        }
      };
      const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
        '/me',
        {
          accessToken,
          parameters: {
            fields: {
              string: 'email,name,first_name,middle_name,last_name',
            },
          },
        },
        responseInfoCallback,
      );
      new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();
    });
  }
});
```

**'Login success with permissions', 'email,public_profile'
and user profile data is**

```
{ first_name: 'XXXXXX',
  name: 'XXXXXX YYYYY',
  last_name: 'YYYYYY',
  id: '1319989423636921696328130092' }
```

But not getting user email id , what is wrong here.
how to get email id after login in Facebook in app.

Comment: And where exactly are you asking the user for the permission necessary to access their email?

Comment: are you able to get name and other details ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I am doing it in my project and successfully retrieving email

```
LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email', 'user_friends']).then(
            (result) => {
                if (result.isCancelled) {
                    console.log('Login cancelled')
                } else {
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                        (data) => {
                            this._fbHome();// Navigatin to next screen
                        }
                    )
                }
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log('Login fail with error: ' + error)
            }
        )
```

Then after navigating to next screen I am extracting user data

```
const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
        '/me?fields=name,email,picture.type(large)',
        null,
        this._responseInfoCallback
      );
      new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();


_responseInfoCallback = (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      alert('Error fetching data: ' + error.toString());
    } else {
      this.setState({ userName: result.name, userEmail: result.email ,userPic:result.picture.data.url});
              AsyncStorage.setItem("UserName",this.state.userName);
                    AsyncStorage.setItem("Email", this.state.userEmail);
                    AsyncStorage.setItem("UserPic", this.state.userPic);

      //  SharedPreferences.setItem("UserName", this.state.userName);
      //       SharedPreferences.setItem("Email", this.state.userEmail);
      //       SharedPreferences.setItem("UserPic", this.state.userPic);
      console.log("Picture"+ this.state.userPic + "Name" + this.state.userName + "Email" + this.state.userEmail);
    }
  }
```

Comment: {id: "1319989428136686664730092", picture: Object, name: "dddddddd"}
id
:
"1319989428136686664730092"
name:"ddddddd"
picture:Object
data:Object
is_silhouette
:falseurl
:
"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.ne

Comment: did you try my method?

Comment: got its working , that issue with account what I used to login , an other account worked.thanks

Comment: Sometimes users have only facebook email id like someone@facebook.com, in that case also email id will be null.

Comment: `logInWithReadPermissions` method no longer supported.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATED**
you set permissions when user is authenticated for example this code

```
LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email'])
        .then(function (result) {
            if (!result.isCancelled) {
                return AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then((data) => {
                    return initUser(data).then((user) => {
                        return {
                            name: user.name,
                            email: user.email,
                            photo: 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + user.id + '/picture?type=normal'
                        }
                    })
                })
            }
        }).then((data) => {
            this._navigateTo(this.props, data, 'Home')
        })
```

set email in your permissions your code could see so

```
LoginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then((result) => {
  if (result.isCancelled) {
    console.log('Login cancelled');
  } else {
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then((data) => {
      const accessToken = data.accessToken;
      const responseInfoCallback = (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          console.log('Error fetching data=', error.toString());
        } else {
          console.log('Success fetching data=', result.toString());
        }
      };
      const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
        '/me',
        {
          accessToken,
          parameters: {
            fields: {
              string: 'email,name,first_name,middle_name,last_name',
            },
          },
        },
        responseInfoCallback,
      );
      new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: what is initUser here

Comment: is a function that call a api for get data of the user function initUser(token) {
    return fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=email,name,friends&access_token=' + token.accessToken)
        .then(response => response.json())
}
export { initUser }

Comment: where to define this

Comment: ReferenceError: initUser is not defined

Comment: in my code i define it in file js call api-client.js

Comment: create this function and import this reference could working!!

Comment: can you see where you define LoginManager

Comment: import {
  LoginManager,
  AccessToken,
  GraphRequest,
  GraphRequestManager,
} from 'react-native-fbsdk';

Comment: in my code  import FBSDK, { LoginManager, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk' in file login.js